Movie with house that has AI and can control itself
I'm looking for a movie in which there is a scene where a young woman is lying in bed and the house's AI system opens the blinds to reveal a beach and then it says something like "Good morning! The temperature is -- degrees!" 
It took place in the future. I am absolutely certain that it was from the early to mid 2000's. They spoke English, and it was in color. I am fairly certain too that it was an action film.  

I think the movie you are looking for is the 2008 movie Iron Man. Check out the scene in this youtube video:



